# Count posts with meta value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, count, metadata

I'm trying to show the number of posts that have certain `meta key` `values` for the current user.

This is my code:

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => $current_user_id,
    'meta_query'        => array(
           'key'        => 'color',
           'value'      => array('red', 'blue')
    ),
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
$the_count = count($posts_array);

echo $the_count;
```

Thi is counting **ALL** posts for the current user, ignoring the `meta key` `values`.

I only need the `$the_count` to be the number of posts that have a `meta key` `value` `'red'` or `'blue'` for the current user.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, but you could try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => $current_user_id,
    'meta_key'          => 'color',
    'meta_value'        => array('red', 'blue')
);

$posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
$the_count = $posts_query->post_count;

echo $the_count;
```

Comment: That actually works, although I swear it never used to (I had tried it that way before). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `meta_query` array, you have to put the `meta_key` and `meta_value` in a subarray:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => $current_user_id,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
           'key'        => 'color',
           'value'      => array('red', 'blue'),
        ),
    ),
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
$the_count = count($posts_array);
```

This is because you can use multiple meta_key to combine them.

```
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
           'key'        => 'color',
           'value'      => array('red', 'blue'),
        ),
        array(
           'key'        => 'size',
           'value'      => array('l', 'xl', 'xxl'),
        ),
    ),
```